# Condition for $\Delta t$ so that the solution of the characteristic polynomial satisfies $|\epsilon|\leq 1 $

Tags: polynomials, proof-verification, characteristic-functions

Show that the characteristic polynomial is given by:

$\epsilon-1+4b_1$sin$^2(\frac{\Delta x}{2})=0$

and what is the condition for $\Delta{t}$ so that the roots of the characteristic polynomial satisfies $|\epsilon | \leq 1$

**EDIT:**

The difference equation considered is:

$P^{l+1}_{k}=wP^{l}_{k-1}+(1-2w)P^{l}_{k}+wP^{l}_{k+1}$ where $w= \frac{\Delta t}{constant*(\Delta x)^2}$

From here onwards the steps of the Neumann stability analysis is followed, which means the following form is substituted:

$P_{k,l}=\epsilon^lexp(-jk\Delta x)$. Now the question is complete.

Comment: How are $\triangle t$ and $\triangle x$ related?  What is a "solution to a polynomial"?  Did you mean roots?

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: Ok, better, but still: What is "a solution to a polynomial"?  Are you trying to bound $\triangle x$?

Comment: I indeed mean the roots.

Comment: I have edited the question, I'd like first and foremost know how the characteristic polynomial is even derived.

Comment: The characteristic polynomial is the *characteristic polynomial of the recurrence relation for the roundoff error*.  This relation is derived from the specific numerical scheme you are using: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_stability_analysis

By far the best source I've seen on this is Introduction á l'analyse numérique des équations aux dérivées partielles / P. A. Raviart, J-M. Thomas (which I haven't seen in any other languages but French), but also the book on numerical methods by G. Marchuk.